# Counting data by date and separate criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following 2 tables

```
TABLE1      
REFNO   XDATE       XNUM
123     01/01/2017  111
456     01/07/2017  111
789     01/01/2017  222

TABLE2  
YNUM    YDATE
111     03/01/2017
111     04/07/2017
222     03/01/2017
222     04/01/2017

Expected Result
REFNO XCOUNT
123   1
456   1
789   2
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to group this data by REFNO. Using the data above, REFNOs 123 & 456 both use XNUM 111, but as the YDATE 04/07/2017 is after 01/07/2017, it is counted under REFNO 456.

So, what I am looking for is a count of YNUM from table 2, based on it's corresponding REFNO.

Comment: could you explain it better? it is unclear what you need.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Done

Comment: What have you tryed at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the matches on dates like this is tricky.  In other databases, I would use a correlated subquery, but that doesn't easily work in Oracle (because the correlation clause is nested too deeply).

Instead let's add the full date range and use `left join`:

```
select t1.refno, count(t2.refno)
from table1 t1
     (select t2.*, lead(xdate) over (partition by refno order by xdate) as next_xdate
      from t2
     ) t1
     on t1.refno = t2.refno and
        t1.ydate >= t2.xdate and
        (t1.ydate < t2.next_xdate or t2.next_xdate is null)
group by t1.refno;
```